# Why do we need to set loop devices when mounting ddrescue images?

Tags: linux, mount, dd, loop-device, ddrescue

In various tutorials I see the following command:

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=123 harddrive.img /mnt/loop
```

but from reading the documentation I can't understand what are loop devices.
Why would `harddrive.img` require different options than `/dev/sba`?

From my own testing `mount -o ro,offset=123 harddrive.img /mnt/loop` seems to work fine so what is the point and the meaning of this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) (which is basically a "fake" block device backed by a regular file) because `mount` needs a block device.

And you don't need to specify `-o loop` because if you don't, a loop device will be created automatically if you try to mount a file. From [mount man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

> The  mount  command  automatically  creates a loop device from a regular file if a filesystem type is not specified or the filesystem is known for libblkid

You can see the loop device is still created even without using `-o loop`:

```
$ sudo mount disk.img /mnt/test
$ lsblk /dev/loop0
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0  100M  0 loop /mnt/test
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep test
/dev/loop0 /mnt/test ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

So `-o loop` is mostly needed if you want to specify an unused or manually created loop device manually, e.g. `-o loop=/dev/loop3`.

Comment: "_`mount` needs a block device._" - no it doesn't. The OP even showed that `mount` with an image file worked fine for them

Comment: Yes, and as I said, it works because the loop file is created automatically in that case not because it is not needed.